# Where/when did the use of "I," in story titles begin? Ex: (I, Robot, and I, Frankenstein)

Tags: book-title

For awhile I've noticed that there have frequently been different stories in different mediums, but especially in literature, where the title begins with "I," followed by a noun or name. I was wondering where this originated and why its use has become so common?

Comment: I see that this is downvoted, maybe because it's about a literary convention rather than standard English usage... I'm not sure if this is off-topic, but I think it's an interesting question and I am also curious.

Comment: 'Me, Tarzan' is just bad grammar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*I, Claudius*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Claudius) was published in 1934. Although there are quite likely to be earlier examples I can't find any. But there's nothing particularly unusual about starting a sentence (for example the first sentence of a speech) this way.

Even the *I, robot* you're thinking of probably [isn't the original](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Robot). Asimov's editor recycled a title from a 1939 story by Eando Binder for a short story collection.

Comment: I don't see why *I, Claudius* couldn't have been the original. It was certainly famous enough imitations of the title.

Comment: @PeterShor, the evidence I've found (or failed to find) so far supports your case. I just have a feeling that given Graves' classical and historical interests there might be some inspiration for the title.

Comment: You're right ... Graves could easily have taken the form of the title from an obscure historical source. But I am fairly sure that all the recent titles of the form are due to *I, Claudius*.

Comment: Seeing as the Wikipedia page says under the category of Later References that with I, Claudius: "The self-referential title has influenced the names of other works of fiction and autobiographies." I'll take this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps/surely(?) the centurys' long wording of *last wills and testaments* ("I, name) had an influence; or perhaps  other legal documents also used that wording.